# Is 3-coloring bounded degree graphs subexponential: $O(\exp{(\sqrt{n}\log^2{n})})$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

We got an argument that 3-coloring bounded degree graphs is subexponential
with complexity $O(\exp{(\sqrt{n}\log^2{n})})$.

The treewidth of a planar graphs on $n$ vertices is $O(\sqrt{n})$
and 3-coloring it is $O(\exp{\sqrt{n}})$.

[This paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s04/www/Lectures/chapter23.pdf) gives reduction from 3-coloring to 3-coloring planar graph
and the main idea is replace each edge crossing with a small gadget,
which preserves colorability.

If for a bounded degree graph we can find drawing with $o(n^2)$ crossings,
we get subexponential algorithm for 3-coloring it.

According to [second paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0255) for bounded
degree graphs, we get approximation with $O(n\log^4{n})$ crossings.

After we have found drawing with few crossings, we planarize using the
gadget. The resulting graph is bounded degree and planar 
and on $n+ C n\log^4{n}$ vertices.

> Q1 Is this result correct?

To our knowledge edge coloring 3-regular graph is exponential.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40723

Comment: “$O(n\log^4n)$-approximation” does not mean a drawing with $O(n\log^4n)$ crossings, but a drawing whose number of crossings is at most $O(n\log^4n)$-times higher than in the optimal drawing. (Also, this is not what the paper proves, but an old result on which it improves.)

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.